# jQuery AutoComplete - How to access return values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to display the values from the returned JSON. I either get [Object object] for each item, or I get nothing at all.

Does anyone know how to display the return values?

```
$('#search-input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("api/autocomplete.php?keyword=" + $("#search-input").val(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function (event, ui) {
                return {
                    label: data.name,
                    value: data.id
                };
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

My JSON looks like this:

> [{name:"item1","id":"1"},{name:"item2","id":"2"},etc..]

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but did you check that the Content-Type header for you api response is set to application/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're mapping `data` (so you want the function to run for every element of the data Array), but you're also using data to set name and id.

So data is still `[{name:"item1","id":"1"},{name:"item2","id":"2"},etc..]` into the function, but `event` should get the current looped item from the Array.

Try something like, and don't forget the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
$('#search-input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("api/autocomplete.php?keyword=" + $("#search-input").val(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function (elementOfArray, indexInArray ) {
                return {
                    label: elementOfArray.name,
                    value: elementOfArray.id
                };
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

Also, ES6 implement [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), It's better to use no-jquery function when possible:

```
response(data.map((elementOfArray, indexInArray) => {
    return {
        label: elementOfArray.name,
        value: elementOfArray.id
    };
}));
```

**Snippet example without ajax**

```js
data = [{name:"item1","id":"1"},{name:"item2","id":"2"}]

console.log(data.map((item, idx) => {
   return {
      label: item.name,
      value: item.id
   };
}));
```